# Unable to add options in select through JSON response in phonegap android application

Tags: javascript, android, json, cordova

I am trying to add options in a dropdown(select) in my application from json response.

Here is my JSON response :

```
{"Value":[{"Sub_Bhav_Copy_Name":"All","Sub_Bhav_id":"0"},{"Sub_Bhav_Copy_Name":"COC Prices","Sub_Bhav_id":"2"},{"Sub_Bhav_Copy_Name":"Cotton Price","Sub_Bhav_id":"4"},{"Sub_Bhav_Copy_Name":"Kapas Prices","Sub_Bhav_id":"1"},{"Sub_Bhav_Copy_Name":"Yarn Prices","Sub_Bhav_id":"3"}]}
```

Here is my js code:

```
function callcottonVarUrl(url) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type : "GET",
        dataType : "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        async : false,
        success : function(msg) {
            jsonRespCtnVar = msg.Value;
            alert(jsonRespCtnVar);
            $("#CategorySelection option").remove();
            $.each(jsonRespFav, function(index, value) {
                cottonVarName = value.Sub_Bhav_Copy_Name;
                cottonVarId = value.Sub_Bhav_id;
                $jsonRespCtnVar = '<option value="'+cottonVarId+'">'+cottonVarName+'</option>';
                $('#CategorySelection').append($jsonRespCtnVar);
            });
        },
        error : function(msg) {
            alert ("error occured");
        }
    });
}
```

And here is .html :

```
    <div id="searchbg">
                    <span>SEARCH&nbsp;COTTON</span>
                    <p id="selectcontainer">
                        <b></b>
                        <select id="CategorySelection" data-native-menu="true" name="" onChange="changetextbox()">
<!--                                <option value="">Please Select Cotton Type</option>       -->
                            </select></p>
                    <div id="search">
                            <input name="" id="searchBox" type="text"
                            placeholder="Enter Commodity"> <a href="#"
                            class="greenbtn" id="button" type="submit"><span class=" sprite"></span></a>

                    </div>
```

but when i tested this there isn't any option generated in dropdown.
Don't know the reason.Any Help ?

Comment: check `jsonRespFav` is empty or not

Comment: What is `jsonRespFav`? Where does that variable get assigned?

Comment: i have declared jsonRespFav at the top and it is assigned as "jsonRespCtnVar = msg.Value;".

Comment: I have also checked the jsonRespFav in alert and it is not empty.It contains five records.

Comment: sorry I got that i have used two different variables....how silly i am...by the way thanks for your concerns.